# Firefox pagespeed bug

Tags: firefox, pagespeed

currently i'm doing some google page speed optimization. on my firefox 26 i have a score of 98 to 99.

a collegue of me has firefox 26 too and there the score is 86? why? the settings seems to be the same.

the most strange thing is that the page speed extension suggests a 200 kb css file to inline. and if watching the resources tab of google page speed the css file has a file size of 0.

The same file in the network tab of firebug is shown with the existing file size

Answer (score 0):

ok - the only solution was to uninstall firefox. reinstall firefox and pagespeed extension. then it works.